# Root only element in nested interval

Tags: limits, analysis, solution-verification

Let $ \{a_n\}_{n \geq 0},\{b_n\}_{n \geq 0}  $ be two sequences. The sequences are given as $ b_n:= \dfrac{a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}}2 $ and $a_n = \frac{c}{b_{n}} $ for $n \geq 1$ with $b_0 = b $ and $a_0 = \dfrac{c}{b}$.

I know that: $$ \frac{a_{0}+b_{0}}{2} > \sqrt{a_{0}b_{0}} $$

And I already proved that: $$ a_n < \sqrt{c} < b_n  $$

Furthermore: $b_{n+1}<b_n$ and $a_{n+1}>a_n$ and $b_n-a_n \le \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\cdot (b_1-a_1) $

Now I tried to prove that $\sqrt{c}$ is the only element in $\bigcap[a_n,b_n]$ for integers n.

Here is my proof:

Suppose there is an x in $\bigcap[a_n,b_n]$ with x $\neq\sqrt{c}$.
For a z>0 we then know:
$\vert x-\sqrt{c}\vert \ge z $. This implies that $\vert b_n-a_n\vert \ge z$.

We know that $b_n-a_n \le \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\cdot (b_1-a_1) $ from above. This leads us to: $ z\le \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\cdot (b_1-a_1) $ and $2^{n-1} \le \frac{b_1-a_1}{z}$.

Let us now define: $w=\frac{b_1-a_1}{z}$ so that: $2^{n-1} \le {w}$. From the Archimedean property we know that for all w (out of the real numbers)  we will find an integer k so that: k>z.
If we set k= $2^{n-1}$ which we can do cause $2^{n-1}$ is a natural number    then $2^{n-1}>w$ which contradicts our assumption.  So there can't be x $\neq\sqrt{c}$ in $\bigcap[a_n,b_n]$.

q.e.d

Is that proof correct? To be honest, I'm not really sure about the Archimedean part...

Comment: The Archimedean principle says that there is *some* $k > w$. You don't get to declare what value of $k$ satisfies the inequality. If you need $2^{n-1} > w$, you will have to demonstrate that $2^{n-1}$ can be used as $k$. But before you get to that, you need to decide what you mean by $n$ here, because you have been really sloppy in your use of that variable. Are you talking about some fixed value of $n$ (which is how you treating it at this point) or are you missing some "for all" statements?

Comment: I can't see how do you know $a_n<\sqrt c < b_n$ in general, and specifically $\sqrt c<b_0$. Did I miss some assumption about the initial value $b$ being large enough...?